# What bitness of VC++ Redistributable is expected by 32bit app on 64Bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, dependencies

I am installing a 32bit app on 64 bit Windows 7. The app requires VC++2013 Redistributable to be installed and directs me to Microsoft Site.

There are two versions of VC++ 2013 Redistributable 32 & 64 bit. However what I need to know is what is really applicable for a 32 bit app on 64 bit Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Probably 32-bit runtime if it's a 32-bit app.

Comment: I just found the answer here on SU itself  https://superuser.com/questions/695704/do-i-need-both-x64-and-x86-versions-of-the-c-redist

Answer (score 0):

The "bitness" of shared libraries (redistributables), such as those provided by Microsoft for Visual C++ (Visual Studio) compiled programs, needs to match the program "bitness", not the OS "bitness".

So a 32-bit program requires the 32-bit version of the redistributables and 64-bit program requires the 64-bit version of the redistributables.